# Вернуть массив строк с++

Tags: c++, массивы, строки, функции

Есть следующая задача: изначально мы не знаем размер массива, который нам надо обработать, необходимо написать функцию, которая бы работала с динамическим массивом и возвращала обработанный массив строк.

```
string fucntion(string* text[]) 
{
   string* text_out=new string[];
   /*
   *do something
   */

   return text_out;
}
```

Каким образом можно вернуть массив строк?

Comment: а `std::vector<std::string>` нельзя использовать?

Comment: @KoVadim и если нельзя, то хотелось бы услышать "почему". И хорошо бы чтоб это было не "так препод сказал".

Comment: @KoVadim, можно, в принципе у меня каких то ограничений нет. А как тогда вектор вернуть?

Comment: Поясню предыдущий комментарий, после замены типа функции у меня ide подсвечивала тип функции т.е. `vector<string> (){ }` как ошибку, в связи с чем я предположил что тип функции таким нельзя объявлять. Сейчас все ок.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Странное смешение французского с нижегородским - массива C и строк C++.

Поскольку массив преобразуется в указатель на первый элемент - просто возвращайте указатель:

```
string* fucntion(string* text[]) 
{
    int N = 20; // Количество элементов массива
    string* text_out=new string[N];
    /*
     *do something
     */

     return text_out;
}
```

Но смотрите, сколько неприятностей: нужно не забыть освободить потом память, при возврате вы не возвращаете количество элементов, а по указателю его вам не узнать. Стоят ли эти неприятности, чтоб ради них отказываться от вектора?

Куда проще так:

```
vector<string> fucntion(/* что там нужно */) 
{
    vector<string> array;
    /*
     *do something
     */

    return array;
}
```

И никаких проблем!